# Can the content description of the Android Application be changed when the new version of the app is uploaded to Google Playstore?

Tags: android, google-play

I am going to upload an app into Google playstore. There is field called content description that must be filled in when the application is going to be displayed in playstore. I was wondering if the data inside the content description can be edited when I upload the new version of my application.

Comment: thank you for the down vote. I request you to find the exact sentence in the documentation stating that content description can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the store description at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Check these answers:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

**YES YOU CAN CHANGE IT ANY TIME**